# For loop returning vectors gives exactly the same results

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe containing BMI-scores of 6390 individuals at 5 different timepoints. From this dataframe, with some missing data, I want to select only those with a BMI <18.5 for each timepoint and put them in separate vectors.

I can do this manually with

```
ondergew1 <- bmir1[bmir1<18.5& !is.na(bmir1)]
ondergew2 <- bmir1[bmir2<18.5& !is.na(bmir2)]
ondergew3 <- bmir1[bmir3<18.5& !is.na(bmir3)]
ondergew4 <- bmir1[bmir4<18.5& !is.na(bmir4)]
ondergew5 <- bmir1[bmir5<18.5& !is.na(bmir5)]
```

However, because I will be performing a lot of similar actions, I would like to get this automated. I tried using:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(bmi)){
  assign(paste0("ondergew",i),bmi[bmi<18.5& !is.na(bmi)])
}
```

But this returns all values <18.5 in the entire dataframe to 5 different vectors. I tried to use the paste0 function to select a different timepoint per loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(bmi)){
  assign(paste0("ondergew",i),paste0("bmir",i)[paste0("bmir",i)<18.5& !is.na(paste0("bmir",i))])
}
```

This does result in 5 different vectors with names ondergew1-ondergew5, but they are all empty. Is there a neat way to solve this problem? I have the bmi-data available in a bmi-dataframe, as well as in seperate bmir1-bmir5 vectors per timepoint.

Comment: Are `bmir1`, `bmir2`, etc 5 different data frames with exactly the same structure? Or are the vectors?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. Bmir1 etc are the vectors, they are combined in the data frame bmi